# Specificity within a text string

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-specificity

I like to think I am very skilled with specificity, but for some reason this one escapes me. Here's my conundrum:

Say you have a list like so:

```
<ul class="dates">
    <li><a href="#">1994/05</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">1999/05</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2001/05</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2005/05</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2014/05</a></li>            
</ul>
```

The css (style-wise, not specificity-wise) is kind of irrelevant here so I'll skip it. But basically, it looks like this:
[image]

My thing is, I want to target the "month section" which is the 05. I want it to be a couple of pixels smaller. These were my failed attempts. They may not even exist and you can laugh all you want, but it beats yelling at the computer for not doing what I want it to do lol.

Comment: You can't select arbitrary letters in CSS, use script to group those letters and wrap in some HTML element then style that element instead.

Comment: There is no nth-letter. Why not just wrap the month in a span tag?

Comment: http://letteringjs.com/

Comment: I can't touch the HTML.  Not my choice trust me. I know I could easily solve this with a span tag,  but since I can't, I figured I reached out to see if anyone has a trick  don't know.

Comment: @LOTUSMS you can't touch the HTML initially but using script to wrap span elements around the letters **dynamically** should not be a problem.

Comment: @king king.  Yeah,  that may do the trick. Do you have a reference where I can see a sample of this script being used?

Comment: I deleted the "imaginary" css by the way

Comment: @LOTUSMS I added the answer using jQuery, hope you know about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery to wrap the month in a span element like this:

```
$('.dates > li > a').html(function(i,oldHTML){
  return oldHTML.replace(/[/](\d{1,2})/, "/<span class='month'>$1</span>");
});
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/8jn9D/1/)

Comment: Thanks bud, this took me out of a jam.

Answer (score 0):

use additional `<span>` with extra class to solve this.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="dates">
  <li><a href="#">1994/<span class="text-small">05</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">1999/<span class="text-small">05</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">2001/<span class="text-small">05</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">2005/<span class="text-small">05</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">2014/<span class="text-small">05</span></a></li>            
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.text-small {
  font-size: 10px
}
```

**RESULT**

[image]

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/raunay/pen/gCouE)

Comment: **Please** remove the OP's CSS which would make other readers confused too much. `nth-letter` is some imaginary thing.

Comment: I know I can use span tags,  but I'm not allowed to alter the HTML.  Hence my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ul class="dates">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="year">1994/</span><span class="month">05</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="year">1999/</span><span class="month">05</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="year">2001/</span><span class="month">05</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="year">2005/</span><span class="month">05</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="year">2014/</span><span class="month">05</span></a></li>            
    </ul>

    <style>
    .year {
    font-size: 12px;
    }

    .month {
    font-size: 10px;
    }
    </style>
```

Comment: I know I can use span tags,  but I'm not allowed to alter the HTML.  Hence my problem.